# How to move this arrow icon little bit down equal to members

Tags: html, css

[image: My image]

please look at this image this I need an arrow icon a little bit down but it is not moving with padding and margin any other way?

## HTML

```
<mat-card-content fxLayout="column" class="content pl-3">
      <span>
        <h6 class="main-line border-bottom pt-2"> Members &nbsp;  <mat-icon class="dia">arrow_right_alt</mat-icon> <span class="numbers">1000</span></h6>
        <h6 class="line border-bottom">Non-Members  <span class="numbers">200</span></h6>
        <h6 class="line border-bottom">Traders  <span class="traders">250</span></h6>
        <h6 class="line border-bottom">Employee  <span class="employee">40</span></h6>
        <h6 class="line border-bottom">-</h6>
        <h6>-</h6>
      </span>

    </mat-card-content>
```

## css

```
.dia{

    // margin-bottom: 4%;
    line-height: 0.2;
    // margin-top: 1%;
    color: #0b4983;
    padding-top: -5px;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: If the parent has a height set, you could try setting `line-height` to the same height.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove `position-absolute` and use the `vertical-align` property.

```css
.dia {
  // margin-bottom: 4%;
  line-height: 0.2;
  // margin-top: 1%;
  color: #0b4983;
  vertical-align: 0.06em;
}
```

```html
<mat-card-content fxLayout="column" class="content pl-3">
  <span>
        <h6 class="main-line border-bottom pt-2"> Members &nbsp;  <mat-icon class="dia">arrow_right_alt</mat-icon> <span class="numbers">1000</span></h6>
  <h6 class="line border-bottom">Non-Members <span class="numbers">200</span></h6>
  <h6 class="line border-bottom">Traders <span class="traders">250</span></h6>
  <h6 class="line border-bottom">Employee <span class="employee">40</span></h6>
  <h6 class="line border-bottom">-</h6>
  <h6>-</h6>
  </span>

</mat-card-content>
```

Comment: not working in my project

Comment: that's weird...would be better if you provided a [mwe](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: @Revanth Also, have you tried changing the `vertical-align` property?

Comment: vertical-align: -0.3em;
  padding-top: 10px;  this worked thanks

Comment: @Revanth Could you mark the answer as accepted if the solution worked?

Answer (score 1):

You can make your `.main-line border-bottom` class a `flexbox` display and define the alignment as centered. That would be much better for responsive design.

Example:

```css
div {
display:flex;justify-content:center;align-items:center;
}

span {
margin:5px;
}

span:nth-child(2){
width:20px;
background:red;padding:5px;color:white;
}
```

```html
<div>
      <span>text</span>
      <span>arrow icon</span>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove "position: absolute" and use the **vertical-align** or **line-height** or **margin-top** properties.

```
.dia{
    line-height: 1.5; /* or more */
}
```

Or

```
.dia{
    vertical-aligne: middle
}
```

Or

```
.dia{
    margin-top: 10px; /* a numbre to center vertical */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There [are several ways to vertically center an element](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/#vertically), please check 2 very quick above:

When you know the height of the element (best render)

```
position:absolute
top:50%
margin-top: -[the height of the arrow / 2);
```

When you don't know or the height is dinamic

```
position:absolute:
top:50%;
transform:translateY(-50%);
```

From experience, in some browsers the second example sometimes 'break a pixel' when trying to position. As it tries to center precisely in the middle, if that means putting 1.234234px it will create an antialising that can make small things look weird. But in some browsers like edge it doesn't.

Answer (score -1):

Add this style on main element

```
.main-line{
   display: flex;
   align-items: center;
   justify-content: space-between;
}
.numbers{
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

Your all text inside the main line element will be vertically centered

Comment: Why the `space-between`? As OP wants the arrow right behind the word. `space-between` would center it.

Comment: by adding margin left auto to number element , you will see the arrow on the extreme right to the members, and the number will be the extreme right of the row

Comment: That was an edit after my comment.

Comment: Yeah, i just forgot to add this thing